How to stop menu from disappearing
I have made a menu where by clicking one icon, the rest become visible. However, it only becomes visible for a second then disappears.
When I press the menu icon, I want the rest to be visible for the whole time, so to permanently change the visibility. For some reason this doesn't work.


function showMenu() {
  var len = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
  for (var i = 0; i < len.length; i++) {
    len[i].style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
.topnav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 98%;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.topnav:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
  transform: scale(2);
}

#welcome {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.button {
  float: left;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topnav a#active {
  background-color: #4bc497;
}

.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Michroma&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="" style="visibility: visible;" onclick="showMenu()" class="button"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">menu</span></a>
  <a href="home.html" id="active" class="button">Home</a>
  <a href="aboutme.html" class="button">About Me</a>
  <a href="projects.html" class="button">Projects</a>
  <a href="contact.html" class="button">Contact Me</a>
  <div class="topnav-right">
    <a href="home.html" class="button"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">home</span></a>
    <a href="aboutme.html" class="button"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">person</span></a>
    <a href="projects.html" class="button"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">workspaces</span></a>
    <a href="contact.html" class="button"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">contact_mail</span></a>
  </div>
</div>




Your click event is on an anchor tag; it's likely reloading the page (the default action of a blank href) immediately after showing the menu.

Can you try like this:   menu



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Michroma&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Menu Example</title>
  <style>
    .topnav {
      position: fixed;
      width: 98%;
      height: 60px;
      overflow: hidden;
      top: 0;
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: white;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .topnav:hover {
      opacity: 1.0;
    }

    .material-symbols-outlined {
      transform: scale(2);
    }

    #welcome {
      margin-top: 80px;
    }

    .button {
      float: left;
      color: #000000;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      height: 50px;
      width: 130px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: underline;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .topnav a#active {
      background-color: #4bc497;
    }

    .topnav-right {
      float: right;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#" style="visibility: visible;" onclick="showMenu(event)" class="button"><span
        class="material-symbols-outlined">menu</span></a>
    <a href="home.html" id="active" class="button">Home</a>
    <a href="aboutme.html" class="button">About Me</a>
    <a href="projects.html" class="button">Projects</a>
    <a href="contact.html" class="button">Contact Me</a>
    <div class="topnav-right">
      <a href="home.html" class="button"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">home</span></a>
      <a href="aboutme.html" class="button"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">person</span></a>
      <a href="projects.html" class="button"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">workspaces</span></a>
      <a href="contact.html" class="button"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">contact_mail</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function showMenu(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior of the anchor element
      var len = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
      for (var i = 0; i < len.length; i++) {
        len[i].style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>



It seems like the issue is with the default behavior of the anchor () element when clicked. By default, clicking on an anchor element () will navigate to the URL specified in the href attribute. To prevent this default behavior and make the menu items visible permanently, you can use the event.preventDefault() method in your showMenu() function.
I added event.preventDefault() in the showMenu() function to prevent the default behavior of the anchor element. This will ensure that the menu items remain visible when clicking the "menu" icon.
